# Not to receive an 'Aliyah when Leining

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, torah-reading, torah-service

I was once told in the name of R' Herschel Schachter that we try to avoid giving the ba'al kriah his own 'aliyah under most circumstances (exceptions would include maftir, a bar mitzvah bochur even on a weekday, and when the ba'al kriah is the only Kohen or Levi).

What is the source for this, particularly considering that originally each 'oleh read his own 'aliyah?

Comment: Someone once told me this so as not to make anyone question the allowance of a Baal Keriya. Seems like a newfangled Chumra to me.

Comment: A similar suggestion would be that the original enactment of the baal keriya, was meant to prevent embarrassing the illiterate. This is accomplished by never having the olim read even when they know how to; masking the incompetent. Having the baal koreh read when he is the oleh, could therefore be viewed as counterproductive.

Comment: @DoubleAA, whaddaya mean "allowance" (or: how would reading one's own section make someone doubt allowance)?

Comment: @msh like using a BK is somehow Bedieved.